# How can I use VLookup to match data from 2 sheets onto a 3rd sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

On sheetA I have a column of names. On sheetB I have those names in a column paired with an ID.

On sheetC I want to have a new column that takes the names from sheetA, matches them with the names on sheetB and returns the relevant ID.

I've been trying to achieve this with `vlookup` but can't quite figure it out. So far on sheetC I have:

```
=xlookup(A3,SheetA!$A$1:$A$600,SheetB!$B$1:$B$600,"not found")
```

The result I want is as follows:

**sheetA**

| A |
| --- |
| John Smith |
| Jane Doe |
| Joe Blow |
| John Smith |
| John Smith |

**sheetB**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| John Smith | 0001 |
| Jane Doe | 0002 |
| Joe Blow | 0003 |

**sheetC - desired outcome**

| A |
| --- |
| 0001 |
| 0002 |
| 0003 |
| 0001 |
| 0001 |

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just add the sheet reference to the first parameter of `XLookup` like so `=XLOOKUP(SheetA!A1,SheetB!A:A,SheetC!B:B,"Not Found")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lookup value `A3` seems incorrect. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(SheetA!A1,SheetB!$A$2:$A$2000,SheetB!$B$2:$B$2000)
```

[image]

Comment: This is strange - I pasted in your code verbatim and still get the error `#NAME?`

Comment: Can you check you have `XLOOKUP()` available to your version of excel? Or due to regional settings you need to use semicolon `(;)` instead of comma `(,)` like `=XLOOKUP(SheetA!A1;SheetB!$A$2:$A$2000;SheetB!$B$2:$B$2000)`.

Comment: Yep, must be a version issue. Tried the in-browser version and it worked. Many thanks!

Comment: @MeltingDog Then use index/match like `INDEX(SheetB!$B$2:$B$600,MATCH(SheetA!A1,SheetB!$A$2:$A$600,0))`.